# Query a Javascript Object (graph)

Tags: javascript, linq, object

I want to search Javascript objects for a specific key and value.
ex.

```
var obj = { zulu: { a: 3, b: "b3", d: true } };
```

Find out if obj contains a key `a` with value `3`. The object has nested objects and arrays of nested objects and `a: 3` can be anywhere in the object graph and in multiple places.

So I can't simple test: `if ( zulu.a == 3 )` as `a` can be in multiple places in the object graph.

I thought `linq.js` looked very promising, however when querying an object it doesn't seem to descend into nested objects. That said I am a complete newb to linq and maybe missing something.

I can (and have) written code to iterate an object graph which handles this, however I'd like to find a general purpose library like linq which would let me perform ad-hoc queries on any JS object.

Comment: If you don't mind being terrible: `var found = false;
JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value){
    if (key === "a" && value === 3){ found = true; }
    return value;
});`

Comment: Thanks, not something I'd considered. That said it is somewhat of a hack. Also the object (graph) can & will be quite large, so performance is an issue as well.

Comment: It's a monster of a hack. I'm glad you recognised that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [js-traverse](https://github.com/substack/js-traverse). Here's `leaves.js` from the README (also in `examples/leaves.js`) adapted to your example:

```
var traverse = require('traverse');

var obj = { zulu: { a: 3, b: "b3", d: true } };

var nodes = traverse(obj).reduce(function (acc, x) {
    if ((! this.isLeaf) && x.a === 3) acc.push(x);
    return acc;
}, []);

console.dir(nodes);
```

Instead of checking for this.isLeaf to be truthy I'm checking for it to be falsy so it captures interior nodes rather than leaves.

The code for js-traverse is written as a CommonJS module, so to use it in a browser you'll need a CommonJS environment like RequireJS, or you could adapt the code in `index.js` to use a global object instead.

Comment: Thanks Ben, looks promising. I'll try it out. Ideally I'd like something like what linq provides, with its collection enumeration etc. however this should do for now.

Answer (score 5):

I'm creator of linq.js. http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Maybe you can use "CascadeDepthFirst" that traverse nested graph.

```
var obj = { zulu: { a: 3, b: "b3", d: true } };
var query = Enumerable.From(obj)
    .CascadeDepthFirst(function (kvp)
    {
        return (kvp.Value instanceof Object) ? kvp.Value : []
    });

// query.ToArray() is
[0] = {Key: "zulu", Value: { a: 3, b: "b3", d: true }}
[1] = {Key: "a", Value: 3}
[2] = {Key: "b", Value: "b3"}
[3] = {Key: "d", Value: true}

// arrangement
var exists = query.Any("$.Key == 'a' && $.Value == '3'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and code example, which works. I am new to linq and don't know enough to understand what your example actually does. I have looked at the reference at [link](http://neue.cc/reference.htm) which didn't help much. Are there any plans to create more extensive English documentation for linq.js?

Comment: I'm glad to help. You can refer to [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) because same as C#, a principle and the behavior. I cannot deny the lack of explanation of an aspect peculiar to an additional method and JavaScript. Though I think, the improvement of document is serious.(because I'm weak in English...) But I do my best little by little.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Linq in JS only C# and .NET.

But in C# Linq will only help you find elements within a collection, as you've discovered.

To solve that I would write an enumerator that walks the tree, called, say, Preorder, then my C# code would look like:

```
foreach(Node n in obj.Preorder)
    if(n.key == "a" && n.value == "3")
    ...
```

Given that you had such an enumerator, I don't see why you couldn't then use linq expressions with it.

Dave.

Comment: Dave, thanks for your reply. I've already written an object enumerator and could use linq.js with that, however I was looking for a more 'all in one' solution where I could write a query to perform the entire task. I was/am surprised that 'linq to objects' doesn't appear to have this capability, or maybe it is a simply a short coming in linq.js.